# Keep a button visible while scrolling a page

Tags: php, html, button, scroll

In a specific page of a web project, I'd like to add a button which "follows" the user while the page is scrolling up and down. With CSS, php, jquery, whatever the way I could do this...
The problem is : I really didn't find any documentation on the web about this (wrong keywords maybe). Where can I find some documentation about it ? Thank you !

Comment: use `position: fixed;` on the button. that will fix it to a certain position of the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you a jsfiddle, I hope this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/o0me03f5/

HTML:

```
<div id="button">button
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content
{
    height:2000px;
}

#button
{
    background-color:gray;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;    
}
```